# Adding React-Router Link as component to Material-UI in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui, styled-components

Hi guys I'm running into the following error when I try to use Material UI's `component` prop to replace the base html element of a component.

**Error**

```
Type 'Props' is not generic.
```

This stems from the following issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15827
(ButtonBaseProps not accepting a component property)

This supposed fix is written in the documentation here: https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-component-prop

*"Now the CustomComponent can be used with a component prop which should be set to 'a'. In addition, the CustomComponent will have all props of a  HTML element.*

*The other props of the Typography component will also be present in props of the CustomComponent.
It is possible to have generic CustomComponent which will accept any React component, custom and HTML elements."*

```
function GenericCustomComponent<C extends React.ElementType>(
  props: TypographyProps<C, { component?: C }>,
) {
  /* ... */
}
```

**Tile.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, ButtonProps } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  width: 100%;
`;

interface Props extends ButtonProps {
  children: string;
  to: string;
}

const Tile = ({ children, to }: Props<Link, { component: Link }>) => (
  <StyledButton component={Link} to={to} variant="contained" color="primary">
    {children}
  </StyledButton>
);

export default Tile;
```

I have limited experience working with Generics. How can I get the `Link` component of `react-router` to work with the Styled MaterialUI `button` in TS?

Comment: you could try to simply just cast Link to ElementType, without use of generics `<StyledButton component={Link as React.ElementType}`

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-component-prop

This is what I ended up using

```
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core";

const AnyComponentButton = <C extends React.ElementType>(
  props: ButtonProps<C, { component?: C }>
) => {
  return <Button {...props} />;
};
```

```
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";

...

<AnyComponentButton
  component={RouterLink}
  to={'/account'}
>
  Go to Account
</AnyComponentButton>
```